# Magento 2 : Installation & Varnish Test Results Failed => Class Does not exist Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento2, varnish, testing, magento2marketplace, class-not-found

We have created the custom module and uploaded to **Magento Marketplace** and **Installation & Varnish Test** has been failed due to **class does not exist**.

> ***If the class not exists, How the Code Sniffer passed?***

[image]
But the class is exists. Don't know why extension is failed.

[image]

We have a custom interface **ConnectorCustomerRepositoryInterface**, The Testing says the class does not exist.

The classes are below:

```
<?php
namespace ABCSolutions\Connector365\Api\Customer

interface ConnectorCustomerRepositoryInterface{
..
}
```

and the extended Class

```
<?php
namespace ABCSolutions\Connector365\Model\ResourceModel;

class CustomerRepository implements \ABCSolutions\Connector365\Api\Customer\ConnectorCustomerRepositoryInterface{
...
}
```

And the `di.xml`

```
<preference for="ABCSolutions\Connector365\Api\Customer\ConnectorCustomerRepositoryInterface" type="ABCSolutions\Connector365\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository"/>
```

And `webapi.xml` file

```
<route url="/V1/connector/Customer_MultiCreate" method="POST">
<service class="ABCSolutions\Connector365\Api\Customer\ConnectorCustomerRepositoryInterface" method="Customer_MultiCreate"/>
<resources>
 <resources ref="Magento_Customer::customer"/>
</resources>
</route>
```

And Installed the Varnish in my local magento system and compiled everything working in my local system.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help on this?

Comment: the ideal situation would be to perform an install of the full code.. I appreciate it is not possible likely. The ideas that come to mind are module dependency here but that is very much a guess

Comment: @Bojjaiah - Please shift you { on next line - I have this issue and with no idea it worked

Comment: @NileshDubey I'm not understood, Please share what you exactly referring.

Comment: ConnectorCustomerRepositoryInterface{ to ConnectorCustomerRepositoryInterface

Comment: @NileshDubey, Yah, I tried that also.

Comment: @Bojjaiah - Sorry and also see here namespace ABCSolutions\Connector365\Api\Customer there is ";" missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got the solution. Everything was fine except my composer. In the composer the **Case sensitivity** is missed of Package and Module Name from `PSR-4` section. Now the extension was passed and under marketing review soon will avail in Magento Marketplace. Thanks to #MagentoTeam on the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the module overriding the CustomerRepositoryInterface is enabled
2. Make sure that after enabling the module, all DIs are compiled properly
3. Make sure that the directory structure of the overriding class matches with the namespace declaration

While you are checking above 3 items, please update your question with the XML file that tells the base CustomerRepositoryInterface is overriden by your custom interface

Comment: Updated my thread please check.

Comment: @Bojjaiah can you please also attach the error report?

Comment: Updated my thread with report card. Please see

Comment: @Bojjaiah does this method really exist both in your Interface and model? `Customer_MultiCreate`

Comment: Yes, exists in both interfaces and `webapi.xml` file. Here the error is `ConnectorCustomerRepositoryInterface` class is not exists. But the class is exists and compiled without error.

Comment: If the class not exists, How the Code Sniffer passed?